# The file-format of a program

Tags: vim, binary, output

I'm wondering in which format the compiled source code of an program written (in C or Rust for example) will result.

I know that the output file is a binary coded file in machine language (like every handbook and documentation explains). I thought that opening the file with an editor of my choice like VIM should show me a lot of 1s and 0s, right? But every time I search the web for that topic, I only find how to open a binary file in VI in hex (mostly using 'xxd').

Isn't there a way to see the binary file like a binary file? --> 100101101111

What is the format of an compiled program?

Comment: when you open a binary file with a text editor you see a representation of `bytes` not `bits` as a printable (or not printable- then you don't even see them) characters.

Comment: Since you mention `vim` and `xxd` I assume you're on a POSIX system (like Linux)? Then read about the [Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). And my advice for you is that you should not try to parse an ELF file yourself, there are libraries that can help you, and even with the help of such libraries you should think long and hard before doing it. And also read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) because your question is one: You tell us you want to read an executable file, but don't tell us the original problem.

Comment: Executable code needs to be *loaded* by the OS, so the code is usually packed into some kind of container format that the OS knows how to read and from which the OS loader can load the relevant parts (data, code, relocations, etc.). The actual program code is in there somewhere, just not right at the top. The closest you can get to a pure code binary is the old [MS-DOS `.com` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ones and zeros are a bit wasteful of screen space, so in 1997, a very clever person discovered that you can pack the information efficiently using the following genius scheme:

```
Binary             Witchcraft
  0000    -->         0
  0001    -->         1
  0010    -->         2
  0011    -->         3
          ...
  1110    -->         E
  1111    -->         F
```

Thus by using the symbols 0, 1, ..., 9, A, B, ..., F, you can represent all of four bits all at once. When you use a contemporary binary data display tool (often referred to as a "hex editor" in honour of this sorcery), you will see the bits of your data shown in this efficient representation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yeah. That's why there was almost no progress in computing before then. It was just really hard to read anything...

Comment: You must be kidding. Or I am misunderstanding you. Binary to hexadecimal conversion is a bit older. Even the ASCII standard is much older.

Comment: I remember I entered programs as hex-codes into our school's Apple-][ already (and could dump it the same). that was quite some time before 1997...

Answer (score 1):

As many people say here, it's probably useless to view a binary file in binary base, but if you want to, `xxd` is precisely a good tool for this (with `-b` option), and you don't need vim to use it:

```
$ cat my_bin_file | xxd -b
```